# Python parameter using arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I am trying to write a Python code that will allow me to list all files in a given folder along with size and creation date. I have gotten this part down. Then I am trying to put in a parameter so it only shows me results over > 1000 in size. Here is what I have so far. I am getting IndexError: list index out of range

EDITED CODE:

```
import os, sys

from datetime import datetime

created = os.stat('.').st_ctime

path = sys.argv[1]

dirs = os.listdir(path)

for file in dirs:

if os.stat(file).st_size == int(sys.argv[2]):
    print(file, os.stat(file).st_size, datetime.fromtimestampcreated)
```

Comment: Did you actually *pass* any command-line arguments?

Comment: I am going to command prompt and typing myfilename.py  D:\SpecificedFolder 1000 in hopes to get all the files over 1000 however it is just listing all files in folder

Comment: You should go ahead and add that information to your question instead of putting it in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

If this was your command line `myfilename.py D:\SpecificedFolder 1000`, your scripts arguments are:

```
sys.argv[1]  # "D:\SpecificedFolder"
sys.argv[2]  # "1000"
```

There are no arguments left for `sys.argv[3]` -> `IndexError`.

Now, another comment. Passing `>` from the command line (as seems to be the intention) is not all the trivial of an interface, because it has its own meaning for the shell (redirection) and will need escaping.

And when dealing with command line arguments. It may look a bit complex/overkill at first, but [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/argparse.html) really offers a lot of comfort features and is very often the right choice,

---

UPDATE: to reflect the comment.

As your code and passed arguments are, you'd need to drop this line:

```
if sys.argv[2] == '>':
```

You can move the following block in a step (left). And change the `sys.argv[3]` reference to `sys.argv[2]`. When it runs, you'd probably notice that you are looking for size equal (`==`), not (equal or) greater than. ;)

Comment: Would I be able to just delete arg 3? I am super noob at coding and learning for fun. Sorry I know this stuff is simple for most.

Comment: No need to apologize. And it's good when learning and coding is fun. I've updated the answer. With those, you should have something that runs. it might be a bigger piece to chew right now, but really mentioned argparse really makes a lot of stuff easy, incl. generating usage message, default values, repeated arguments, inputs validation,....

Comment: Thank you so much for clearing that up for me. Is there a way to instead of looking for a specific size looking for all sizes greater then a specific size for example using -gt instead of > to reduce the problems when running the code? I have updated my code in the main section to reflect the changes

Comment: Yes, could make your script take arguments like `script.py dir/ -gt 1000`. You could then back to your current if clause... and must supply all three arguments on the command line. That is one of the issues you will run into once you start adding optional arguments and deal with possibly combinations thereof. It can get cumbersome quite quickly.